# android updated system app, how to remove the "updated" status?

Tags: link2sd

[image: link2sd screenshot]

**link2sd** can list  all updated system apps. as this screenshot shows.

I thought that link2sd categorize an app as **UPDATED** when it finds the same app in `/data/app` and `/system/app`. So I deleted the Gmail app from `/system/app`, and the corresponding file from `/data/dalvik-cache`. but link2sd still say Gmail is updated.

I'm just wondering, based what criterion that link2sd categorize an app as UPDATED?